# C# Test Driven Development

Tags: c#, tdd

I am trying to carry out some simple test driven development tests using C#. However I have no real experience with this and am having some trouble.

The test I am trying to carry out is for login authentication. Below is what I have so far.

```
using System;

namespace TimetableSystem 
{
    public class Timetable 
    { 
        public bool TimetableLogin(string username, string password)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Test Method

```
using System;
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using TimetableSystem;

namespace TimetableSystemTests
{
    [TestClass]
    public void TestLoginMethodValid()
    {
        Timetable auth = new Timetable();
        bool result = auth.TimetableLogin("Name", "Password"); 
        Assert.IsTrue(result);
    }
}
```

This test keeps failing and I'm unsure why thanks for any help.

Comment: Well your implementation is coded just to throw `NotImplementedException`, whereas you're expecting it to return true...

Comment: Having said that, your code isn't valid anyway - you're currently trying to declare a method directly in a namespace. You need to declare a class, and declare the method within the class.

Comment: *This test keeps failing and im unsure why*...I mean it seems pretty obvious to me. Your aserting that result is `true`is result true? or does something else happen when you run the code? Like maybe a `NotImplementedException()`getting thrown? Does this equal true?

Comment: Check your password in TimeTableLogin function and accordingly return boolean value.

Comment: What do you expect in your test if your implementaion throws an exception? Of course it´ll fail. In fact it won´t even *reach* the `Assert`-statement, as the exception will break your execution.

Comment: Not sure why he's getting downvoted tho, the question isn't cryptic, he included his code, took some time to prepare his post ?

Comment: @alexandreBeaudet I'm not one of the downvoters, but it's most likely because if he just put a debugger on the first line of his test, and stepped through (it's only three steps max) then he would see why, so this is not a useful resource to be maintained on SO

Comment: @LordWilmore I do understand that the question could be really simple to solve, and even obvious for anyone, but the asker could be a student just starting out development, or that kind of profile, I do think that there is no stupid question. The minimum if you downvote is to give an explanation in the comment section :/ ... But he got his answer anyway so everything is good ! :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The test is failing because you haven't implemented the login method yet (see the NotImplementedException), this is by design in test driven development.  You write enough code so that the method and test compile without implementing it, then you go to work implementing your method so that the test will pass.

Inject a login service into your TimeTable class:

```
public interface ILoginService
{
   bool Login(string username, string password);
}

public class TimeTable
{
   ILoginService _loginService;
   public TimeTable(ILoginService loginService)
   {
     _loginService = loginService;
   }

   public bool TimeTableLogin(string username, string password)
   {
      return loginService.Login(username, password);
   }
}
```

Then create a mock in your test project as an implementation for your login service.  This version of the service is for testing only.

```
public MockLoginService : ILoginService
{
   public bool Login(string username, string password)
   {
     return (username == "Name" && password == "Password");
   }
}
```

Then in the test:

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLoginMethodValid()
{
  MockLoginService mockLoginService = new MockLoginService();
  Timetable auth = new Timetable(mockLoginService);
  bool result = auth.TimetableLogin("Name", "Password"); 
  Assert.IsTrue(result);
}
```

Now you are testing the logic inside TimeTable.TimetableLogin and not the login service.  Next you implement the real version of your ILoginService to be used in production and you can have confidence that TimeTable.TimetableLogin will perform as expected.

Comment: @Kyle B Thank you again for your help!

Comment: Creating a Mock is certainly one solution, you'd be better off using a Mock library (like Moq) which will let you create only the functions that you need rather than building out an entire class.

Comment: @AdamHess, I agree, I felt like I should start with the basics here since it seemed like a beginner question

Comment: @AdamHess, creating mocks by yourself will protect you in some way from having "big" classes and interfaces ;)